# Lotka Volterra existence of solution proof??

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following differential system:

$$\begin{cases} x'=x-xy\\ y'= -y+xy \\ x(0)=x_0>0\\ y(0)=y_0>0 \end{cases}$$. How can I show that this system has a unique solution defined on a fixed interval $[0,T]$? I can't see how to apply Picard Lindelof theorem, because I can't prove that the function $f:[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$, given by:

$$f(t,x,y)=(x-xy, -y+xy)$$ is uniform Lipschitz in $t$. Any ideas?

Comment: Was going to say use Cauchy-Lipschitz, which for small enough $T$ surely has to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system has a first integral
$$
\frac{\dot y}{\dot x}=-\frac{y(x-1)}{x(y-1)}\implies \frac{\dot y}y(y-1)+\frac{\dot x}{x}(x-1)\implies y-\ln y+x-\ln x=C
$$
and the level sets of that function are bounded. As solution curves follow the level sets, they are bounded too and thus solutions exist for all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Can you give a little more details? I don't understand too clear your reasoning.

Comment: This was just a short way towards the first integral. That it exists for the basic Lotka-Volterra model is well-known. More complicate predator-prey models do not have this property, there you need to find Lyapunov functions or other bounding arguments.

Comment: But if we add a control $0\leq u(t)\leq 1$, then we cannot proceed by the same method, isn't it?                                                             $$\begin{cases} x'=x-u(t)xy\\ y'= -y+u(t)xy \\ x(0)=x_0>0\\ y(0)=y_0>0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: That is correct. You could still use the level sets of this function or some modification like $H_t=u(t)\,(x+y)-ln(xy)$ to analyze the behavior of the solution, but they will cross the level sets in general. The trick is to have a function where at least some level sets are crossed in one direction only.